# python regular expression with "OR" and $ end of line

Tags: python, regex

I have 3 different types of string in which I'm trying to match a pattern:
Patterns:

1. abcdedf_abc_abc_XS123456789_1234567
2. abcdedf_abc_abc_AB_1234567_2014/03/17
3. abcdef_abcdf_abc_xyz_12354AB12_1234567

In each case I'm tying to match '1234567'

The code that I have tried is:

```
m = re.search(r'_[0-9]+_|$',string)
m = re.search(r'_[0-9]+[_]|$',string)
```

None seem to be giving me the results that I want.

From http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html I have read that:

"Alternation, or the “or” operator. If A and B are regular expressions, A|B will match any string that matches either A or B. | has very low precedence in order to make it work reasonably when you’re alternating multi-character strings. Crow|Servo will match either Crow or Servo, not Cro, a 'w' or an 'S', and ervo."

A and B must be regular expressions. I'm guessing that $ is not a regular expression.

Comment: I'm confused by the question. The code looks like you're searching for '_[0-9]+_|$' and not '123457'.

Comment: The end result I'm looking for is 1234567. I'm using the _ at the start of the pattern b/c each time there is a 1234567 it is preceded by a _. So I strip the _ after I find a match.

Comment: looks like @thefourtheye answered it. But he used an older version of python. You may need to use parentheses to print :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
strings = [
"abcdedf_abc_abc_XS123456789_1234567",
"abcdedf_abc_abc_AB_1234567_2014/03/17",
"abcdef_abcdf_abc_xyz_12354AB12_1234567"
]

import re
pattern = re.compile(r"(?<=_)\d+(?=_|$)")
for item in strings:
    print pattern.search(item).group()
```

**Output**

```
1234567
1234567
1234567
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/LQNGNABVZX30V_be)

Comment: @WongSifu I included Debuggex demo in my answer. Please check that. If you have any question, please comment here :)